model loss value for each epoch in sentence transformers framework
I'm trying to fine-tune a pre-trained language model using sentence transformers.
The model I'm using is based on Bert.
the method I'm using is fine-tunning via a siamese network so in order to do that I made a pair dataset and labeled each datapoint .
I want to fine tune the model for some epochs but I don't know how many epochs should I use.
Other libraries like torch may help but I use sentence transformers now.
It seems to have no callback procedure or at least I don't know it.
I want to access the model accuracy and loss value for each epoch.
this is my model fine-tunning function
def fine_tune_model(i):
  """fine tunes the model for 1 epoch each time and saves the model to a path"""


  data = dataset['train']

  train_samples = []
  for row in tqdm(data):
    train_samples.append(InputExample(
        texts=[row['Sent 1'], row['Sent 2']],
        label=row['class']
    ))

  batch_size = 8
  loader = DataLoader(train_samples, batch_size=batch_size,
  shuffle=True
                      )

  # model = SentenceTransformer("sbunlp/fabert")
  bert = models.Transformer("sbunlp/fabert")
  pooler = models.Pooling(
      bert.get_word_embedding_dimension(),
      pooling_mode_mean_tokens=True
  )

  model = SentenceTransformer(modules=[bert, pooler])

  loss = losses.SoftmaxLoss(
      model=model,
      sentence_embedding_dimension=model.get_sentence_embedding_dimension(),
      num_labels=3
  )

  epochs=1
  warmup_steps=int(0.1*len(data))

  model.fit(
      train_objectives=[(loader, loss)],
      epochs=epochs,
      warmup_steps=warmup_steps,
      output_path=model_repo +f'/sbert_test_{i}',
      show_progress_bar=True
  )

and this is evaluation function I wrote .
def model_eval_proccess(i, output_file=output_file, rang=1000):
  """ evaluates the model based on a sample of 1000 slice of test dataset and returns a score to csv"""

  dev_data = dataset['test']
  dev_data = dev_data.select(range(0, rang))
  dev_samples = []
  for row in tqdm(dev_data):
    dev_samples.append(InputExample(
        texts=[row['Sent 1'], row['Sent 2']],
        label=row['class']
    ))

  batch_size = 8
  dev_loader = DataLoader(dev_samples, batch_size=batch_size,
  shuffle=True
  )

  model = SentenceTransformer(model_repo +f'/sbert_test_{i}')
  loss = losses.SoftmaxLoss(
    model=model,
    sentence_embedding_dimension=model.get_sentence_embedding_dimension(),
    num_labels=3
    )
  evaluator = evaluation.LabelAccuracyEvaluator(dataloader=dev_loader, name='my_eval', softmax_model=loss, write_csv=True)
  e = evaluator(model)
  text = f"for this epoch the accuracy of model is {e} ."

